# Prove a binomial inequality

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I would like to prove the following inequality:

$$
{m+n \choose m} \ge \frac{(n+1)^m}{m!}
$$

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\binom{m+n}{m} = \frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+m)}{m!}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Put $n + m$ balls in $n + 1$ boxes, one in each except $m$ balls in the last one.